# ¿Por qué para cerrar una pregunta son necesarios estos dos elementos?

Tags: soporte

Mi duda surge a partir de estas dos preguntas:

- [Error # 8134 (Divide by zero error encountered ) - replicacion base de datos SQL Server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108872/error-8134-divide-by-zero-error-encountered-replicacion-base-de-datos-sql)
- [Error # 8134 Divide by zero error encountered - Error al crear instantánea publicación transaccional SQL Server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108886/error-8134-divide-by-zero-error-encountered-error-al-crear-instant%C3%A1nea-publi)

Es la misma pregunta creada por usuarios diferentes pero con el mismo nombre. Bueno, el punto es que al cerrar la segunda pregunta como duplicado de la primera obtengo este mensaje:

> Esta pregunta no tiene una respuesta con votos a favor o aceptada

¿Por qué es necesario para marcar como duplicada tenga al menos una respuesta con votos a favor o aceptada?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marcar una pregunta como duplicada es una manera de decirle a OP: *tu pregunta ya se realizó antes y fue respondida, ve y mira esa respuesta*. De hecho,cuando votas para cerrar una pregunta como duplicado el texto es

> Esta pregunta ya se hizo y tiene una respuesta.

Este tema se ha tratado varias veces en meta.stackoverflow.com,por ejemplo [Why is it that the lack of an answer prevents the marking of a question as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256054)

Básicamente sería injusto que alguien tuviera un problema y,sólo porque alguien ya lo preguntó anteriormente y no recibó ninguna respuesta, no pudiera hacer su pregunta.

Existe obviamente una excepción a esta regla ([Closed question as duplicate of unanswered question by same user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341107)), y es si la pregunta es del mismo usuario, en ese caso marcar como duplicada está permitido (para evitar que el mismo usuario realice la misma pregunta una y otra vez).

En el ejemplo que pones, aunque parece que es efectivamente la misma persona, son dos usuarios diferentes y por eso no permite cerrar como duplicado.

En estos casos, la opción sería cerrar la pregunta duplicada con otro motivo. Yo propondría *no relacionado* y en el motivo explicar la situación.